# How can I retrieve the contents of an iTerm session with Applescript?

Tags: applescript, iterm2, iterm

I am working on an Applescript to make logging into 2-factor authentication domains a little easier. Long story short, instead of using delays and sending text, I'd like to poll the contents of the current session and enter usernames/passwords/tokencodes as soon as the prompt for them appears. Luckily, iTerm v3.X has a bunch of cool AppleScript stuff: 
https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html

But I'm having a lot of trouble reading the contents of the terminal session. Here's what I've got so far:

```
on run
# Start or activate iTerm
tell application "iTerm"
    activate

    tell the first window
        # Create a new tab, which will create a new session inside
        set newTab to (create tab with default profile)
        tell newTab
            # Since we just created the tab, there should only be one session right now.
            repeat with aSession in sessions
                tell aSession
                    delay 3
                    #set myvar to (tty)
                    #set myvar to (text)
                    set myvar to (contents)
                    #do shell script "echo " & myvar & " >> ~/some_file.txt"
                    #write text (contents)
                end tell
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
return myvar
end run
```

As you can see, I've tried several different things, "contents" seemed like the most promising solution according to the documentation, but crazy stuff comes out, like this:

```
session id "0986F3BD-D2AF-480F-B517-AB7A43B2A0C4" of tab 3 of window id "window-1" of application "iTerm"
```

What is this stuff? Why don't I see what I expect, which is something like this:

```
Last login: Fri Jun 10 18:18:22 on ttys001
me@MacBook-Pro:~|⇒
```

Comment: In my item2 version "Build 2.9.20160313", your script works fine and gets exactly what expected. I ran this script by 'Script Editor'.

Comment: Well, I downloaded that version and I swear I got this script to work 3 or 4 times in a row, but as soon as I started editing my script again, it started returning that crazy stuff about session ID again. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, or what is going wrong.

Comment: did you run your script from 'Script Editor' or in other ways ? I don't understand the meaning of 'in a row'...

Comment: Yes, I am editing and running the script from Script Editor. Also, sorry, "In a row" is an english idiom. The closest literal definitions I can think of are "in succession" or maybe "one after another", though that also might be an idiom.

Comment: Got it :) http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+row . Glad that you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work for a good 3-5 times in a row, but as soon as I edited my script again, it started returning that session ID stuff. At that point, I decided that applescript or iTerm's applescript API is just too opaque. I hammered out a workaround that actually seems to work pretty well, here it is for anyone who comes after me:

```
on grepCountsFor(searchString)
    set terminalContents to my getContents()
    log "terminal contents: " & terminalContents

    set oneline to ""
    set allRecords to paragraphs of terminalContents
    repeat with aRecord in allRecords
        if length of aRecord is greater than 0 then
            set variable to aRecord
            log "variable: " & variable
            set oneline to oneline & variable
        end if
    end repeat

    log "oneline: " & oneline
    set command to "echo \"" & oneline & "\" | grep -o \"" & searchString & "\" | wc -l"

    log "command: " & command
    set counts to do shell script command
    return counts as number
end grepCountsFor

on getContents()
    #iTerm needs to be in the front for key presses to register.
    my waitForWindow("iTerm")
    # Mush buttons in the app
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "a" using command down
        keystroke "c" using command down
        set sessionContents to do shell script "pbpaste"
    end tell
    return sessionContents
end getContents

# Waits for a window to come into focus
on waitForWindow(appName)
    # Poll until "appName" is the active window
    set activeApp to "noApp"
    repeat until activeApp is appName
        set activeApp to (path to frontmost application as Unicode text)
        # If the active app name does not contain the target, 
        # try to activate it again.
        if appName is not in activeApp then
            tell application appName
                activate
            end tell
        else
            # Done
            exit repeat
        end if
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
end waitForWindow
```